# Mysql between operator showing only the first row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, between

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bcl1_logs where created_at between '2015-02-07' and '2015-02-10'
```

and a table like this:

```
 0 =  "id":1,
      "pc_name":"BCL101",
      "created_at":"2015-02-07 22:25:44"


 2 =  "id":2,
       "pc_name":"BCL101",
       "created_at":"2015-02-07 22:25:44"

 3 =  "id":3,
       "pc_name":"BCL101",
       "created_at":"2015-02-10 22:25:44"
```

When i query my statement, it's only showing the first two rows with '2014-02-07' date and it does not include the date with '2015-02-10' when my query is BETWEEN dates '2014-02-07' and '2015-02-10'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add time into your query

```
SELECT * FROM bcl1_logs where created_at between '2015-02-07 00:00:00' and '2015-02-10 23:59:59'
```

Comment: There! as simple as this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you only use the date part, the time part is set to `00:00:00`. So your query looks like

```
 created_at between '2015-02-07 00:00:00'  and '2015-02-10 00:00:00'
```

And that do not include the third record with time `22:25:44`.

change to:

```
 created_at between '2015-02-07 00:00:00'  and '2015-02-10 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

`value between X and Y` means `value >= x AND value < y`, so `'2015-02-10'` is left out. If you want to use the `between` operator and include it, you need to add an additional day:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   bcl1_logs 
WHERE  created_at BETWEEN '2015-02-07' AND '2015-02-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers explain the issue that you are comparing a date with a date and time, so try using `DATE()` in the query:

```
SELECT * FROM bcl1_logs WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2015-02-07' AND '2015-02-10'
```